# when i clicked disabled button by index that i pass it to function react.js

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, {
    Component
}
from 'react';

class MyApp extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            arr: [1, 2, 3, 4],
            disabled: false
        };
    }
    clicked = (index) = > {
        this.setState({
            disabled: true
        })
    }
    render() {
        const maparray = this.state.arr.map((index, MapArray) = > {
            return {
                MapArray
            }
        }) return ({
            maparray
        });
    }
}
export
default MyApp;
```

Comment: I don't understand the question...can you reformulate?

Answer (score 0):

clicked = (index) = > {document.getElementBYid(index).disavled=true;})}
 render() {const maparray = this.state.arr.map((index, MapArray) = > {
 return { MapArray